# Parse Coldfusion 9 generated JSON response in Cocoa Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an NSDictionary instance created via

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

from a Coldfusion generated JSON response with a output similar to this:

```
{"ROWCOUNT":1,"COLUMNS":["SUBSCRIBERID","FIRSTNAME","LASTNAME"],"DATA":{"SUBSCRIBERID":[
27775],"FIRSTNAME":["John"],"LASTNAME":["Doe"]}}
```

What I'm trying to do is enumerate the *DATA* objects but struggling with the syntax.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "DATA" object is just a dict, so doing this would enumerate that dict:

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [response objectForKey:@"DATA"];    
[dataDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        // do your work here 
}];
```

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't see forest for trees. Couldn't be any simpler.